# ¿Qué quiere decir "compuesto" en la expresión "compuesto y sin novia"?

Tags: modismos

De golpe me vino a la cabeza la expresión **"compuesto y sin novia"** (con todas sus posibles combinaciones de "compuesto/a", "novio/a").

El "Abecedario de dichos y frases hechas" de Guillermo Suazo Pascual (consultado vía Google Books) lo define como:

> Se emplea para señalar que no se ha logrado lo que se deseaba después
>   de muchos preparativos, porque algo ha fallado en el último momento.
>
> Como se puede ver, se aplica a las mujeres porque eran las más
>   abandonadas en el altar, aunque se utiliza referida a situaciones en
>   la que los implicados son hombres o mujeres indistintamente.

El significado es claro: estar preparado para algo para que en el último momento falle y uno se quede sin nada. Ahora, me pregunto: ¿a qué se refiere "compuesto" exactamente? La RAE menciona muestra diferentes acepciones para dicha palabra...

> [**compuesto, ta**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=fI2tR6J3xDXX2xbjCXW9)
>
> (Del part. irreg. de componer; lat. composĭtus, part. de componĕre,
>   componer).
>
> 1. adj. Mesurado, circunspecto.
> 2. adj. Bot. Se dice de las plantas angiospermas, dicotiledóneas, hierbas, arbustos y algunos árboles, que se distinguen por sus hojas
>      simples o sencillas, y por sus flores reunidas en cabezuelas sobre un
>      receptáculo común; p. ej., la dalia, la pataca, el ajenjo, el alazor,
>      la alcachofa y el cardo. U. t. c. s. f.
> 3. adj. Gram. Dicho de un vocablo: Formado por composición de dos o más voces simples; p. ej., cortaplumas, vaivén.
> 4. m. Agregado de varias cosas que componen un todo.
> 5. m. Quím. cuerpo compuesto.
> 6. f. pl. Bot. Familia de las plantas compuestas.

Pero ninguno de ellas para mí tiene relación con "preparado" o un significado similar al que la expresión sugiere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo me quedo con la acepción número 4.

> m. Agregado de varias cosas que componen un todo.

Me imagino a alguien **plantado en el altar**. Tiene ahí a todos los invitados, al cura, el padrino, los anillos, el traje de boda, el catering está preparado para después de la ceremonia... pero a pesar de tener todo eso falla (o falta) lo fundamental (la novia) y es imposible seguir adelante. Por tanto "no se ha logrado lo que se deseaba después de muchos preparativos, porque algo ha fallado en el último momento."

"Compuesto" se referiría a todos esos preparativos que son necesarios (componen el "todo" de la boda) y lo de la "novia" es obvio. Sin novia, no hay boda, auqnue tengas todo lo demás.

Comment: Es decir que "compuesto y con novia" sería algo así como "preparado para la boda pero sin novia", ¿verdad? Es curioso porque inicialmente pensé que la expresión tendría una connotación algo peor: "no solo se quedó sin novia, sino que se quedó solo de solemnidad" o similar. Leyendo mi referencia y tu respuesta me doy cuenta que no es tan catastrofista (dentro del drama que tal situación puede representar, ¡claro!)

Comment: Yo creo que el significado que se le da popularmente a «compuesto» en este caso no aparece entre las acepciones que da el DRAE para esa palabra, y tiene más que ver con la «compostura»: *[a]seo, adorno, aliño de alguien o algo*. También se puede deducir mejor de «componer(se)»: *[e]ngalanar a alguien.* Es decir, arreglado, bien vestido, aseado, en definitiva, como dice @Diego, preparado para la boda, pero a falta de lo más importante para ella.

Comment: Estoy con @guillem, No sirve la defición normal de compuesto en este caso, se acerca más a la de componese. Por cierto muy buena pregunta.